# I can not open hello.py using python

Tags: python-2.7

I have installed python 2.7 in H:\Py
and the google-python-exercises is in H:\Py too

when I opened Python2.7 IDLE(python GUI),and typed !

```
python Hello.py
```

then print red word like below

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

so how can I run hello.py?

Comment: So, what is the content of `Hello.py` then which causes a SyntaxError?

Comment: the "Hello" becomes red,

Comment: To clarify, do you mean the "Hello" in the command "python Hello.py" becomes red? It sounds like you're typing `python Hello.py` into a REPL and not a command prompt. What does the start of the line look like? "H:\py>"? ">>>"? Something else? Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Yes, I mean the "Hello" in the command "python Hello.py" becomes red...and the start of the line look like >>......my reputation is not enough to have a screenshot  .and what does REPL mean? thanks

Comment: Please post the code inside `Hello.py`. You don't need any reputation to do that!!

Comment: import sys

# Define a main() function that prints a little greeting.
def main():
  # Get the name from the command line, using 'World' as a fallback.
  if len(sys.argv) >= 2:
    name = sys.argv[1]
  else:
    name = 'World'
  print 'Hello', name

# This is the standard boilerplate that calls the main() function.
if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()

Answer (score 0):

IDLE's Read-eval-print-loop (REPL) window can't execute programs that way. You need a command prompt.

If you are in Windows, hold shift and right click on the folder that contains your project. Select "Open command window here". Enter `python Hello.py` into that window.